# Si tengo muchos flujos alternativos en una especificación de casos de uso, debo crear para cada flujo un diagrama de secuencias?

Tags: uml

El caso es que tengo casos de uso con muchas validaciones, por ende, muchos flujos, entonces para plasmar un caso de uso que tiene muchos flujos alternativos, debo crear un diagrama de secuencias para cada flujo alternativo?, de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Tienes algún código? Sin código será difícil poderte ayudar

Comment: Si haces un diagrama, con todos esos flujos, ¿te resultaría fácil entenderlo?, ¿lo entenderían los colaboradores de tu equipo? ... si es así, nada te impide hacerlo. En otro caso, **divide y gobierna**